# Add a temporary column in mysql who's entries are counts of same entries of a table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, relational-database

So I have this database which contains in it a list of files. Files can be updated, but the previous versions are still held on to in case of rollbacks. What I want to know is how would I add a temporary column that contains the number of previous versions for that file.

Essentially, how would I crate a temporary column in mysql who's entries depend on something within the main table?

```
CREATE TABLE Files(
    file_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    student_id INTEGER,
    group_id INTEGER,
    submission_number INTEGER,
    submission_type VARCHAR(10),
    FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES Student (student_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES Groups(group_id)ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

A submission is defined by its submission_number and submission_type. So submission_type 0 would be an assignment, 1 would be a project, 2 would be a quiz and so on. submission_number would be which assignment of that submission type we are uploading. So for example, the third quiz will have a submission_type =2 and a submission_number = 3. we can update a file, so we can upload a new file with the same submission_type and submission_number. What I want to return is a table which contains the number of times each submission had an upload.

So if i had the following table

```
+---------+------------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
| file_id | student_id | group_id | submission_number | submission_type |
+---------+------------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
|       1 |      10049 |        1 |                 1 |   assignment    |
|       2 |      10032 |        1 |                 1 |   assingment    |
|       3 |      10032 |        1 |                 2 |   quiz          |
|       4 |      10032 |        1 |                 3 |   assingment    |
+---------+------------+----------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

I would want to return the table

```
+-------------------+-----------------+-------+
| submission_number | submission_type | count |
+-------------------+-----------------+-------+
|                 1 |      assignment |   2   |
|                 2 |      quiz       |   1   |
|                 3 |      assignment |   1   |
+-------------------+-----------------+-------+
```

Another way to think about it, if submission_number and submission_type were coordinates instead, say x,y then i want to count the number of times the same point appears in the table. So the point (1,assignment) appeared twice thus the count is 2.

Comment: do you want the count based on each submission number??

Comment: The count is based on how many times a submission with the same submission_number and submission_type is uploaded. think of submission_number and submission_type as (x,y). How many times do we have the same point appear in this table.

Comment: can same submission number have two different submission type?? Like in your table for file_id 2 can submission_type  be other than 1? and what should be the result then?

Comment: Yeah it can. I just updated the question hopefully its clearer. Think of it like this. in your class you have 5 assignments, 3 quizzes and 1 project. then the assignments will be represented by the submission numbers 1,2,3,4 and 5. However, you can update a file and submit another version to the same submission_number. So in this case we uploaded 2 versions of the first assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another table just to do that. Just write a query using `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT submission_number, submission_type, COUNT(file_id) FROM Files GROUP BY submission_number, submission_type;
```

[working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d669dc/2)

Comment: Oh man thank you so much! I just started using SQL for the first time a couple of days ago

Comment: welcome :) and let me know if you have any more query regarding this question.